# how to design a string that varies one time per day in spring,JAVA？

Tags: java

## here is the thing:

in `spring`，a service class，`singleton`，i need a string which means the current yyyy-mm-dd，so it cannot be declared final and neednot to be static(singleton).

`my way` is to obtain current time everytime when using this string first time.

since it varies per day，is there a better way？

Comment: Use a method, not a member variable, eg `String getCurrentDate(){...}` in this way it can be calculated each time it is called. If needbe you can even throw Spring's caching at it to prevent recalculation too often.

Comment: is this seems too often?each time called?

Comment: @counterFish Hence the caching, so string is not built on each call, only on first call of the day.

Comment: @Andreas with caching, can it ensure next day this string changes?

Comment: Yes, if you detect when the cache should be refreshed, i.e. on first call after midnight.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
@Component
public class TodayService {

    private volatile String today;

    public String getToday() {
        return today;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Scheduled("some cron expression meaning every midnight")
    void update() {
        today = "formatted date string for " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes you have scheduling running, a presumption you don't mention. What you OP don't?

Comment: Business needs this string varing everyday ,the server runs everytime.Your way is supposed be working. OP ??